# VS 2017 sandbox stuck on welcome screen

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, roslyn, vsix

This happens on blank "Analyzer with Code Fix (NuGet + VSIX)" template.
When I run Vsix project the screen of sandbox stays at welcome screen and nothing happens.

Normal VS works fine and "VSIX Project" template also starts sandbox correctly so there seem to be an issue only with this specific template.

I don't want to mess to much with the template as I'm following tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to change command line arguments under vsix project properties->debug from `/rootsuffix Roslyn` to `/rootsuffix Exp`and it works